# GridView Please Stop Scrolling... Please Fit Inside Parent Layout

Tags: android, xml, gridview

[image]

I Have this Grid view,, Inside a LinearLayout

LinearLayout Height is match_parent or fill_parent
GridView Height is fill_parent or match_parent

But it still leaves that empty space...
i want to stretch the Gridview Content to fill LinearLayout

Please Help!

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `how i can stop scrollview and fit all the items inside the GridView` what ???

Comment: @Sam please look at my answer, I hope I could help

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Added Pic Now...

Comment: @superuser sorry till the same....

Comment: Can't see the pic. Are you embedding it using some url?

Comment: @M-WaJeEh  Sorry -- Now you can see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I can see what you are doing. Its simply not possible. Even if you do it using hacks that are strongly discouraged, you will be breaking all the laws of using `GridView` and `ListView`. I strongly suggest you not to use `GridView` here. Instead make this layout using simple nested `LinearLayout`s or `TableLayout`. `GridView` and `ListView` are supposed to scroll. Anyways `android:layout_weight="float"` param will be useful for you while making this layout using `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the linear layout and of the scroll view to **wrap_content**. What this does is **makes the view group you set it to only as large as what ui components it contains**.
Do this to your LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

android this to you scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Added pic please help